# Removing rows from csv file before a particular row based on values in that row using Pandas

Tags: python, linux, pandas, csv

I have csv file and that looks like following. I want to remove all rows before one row values [Station Mac, First time seen,Last time seen, Power, packets, BSSID,Probed ESSIDs] for further processing.I am using panadad libarary in python to read this csv file. I am able to remove particular rows by index, but my file reload after fes seconds nad row index can be changed. How should I do this.
your help will be appreciated.

```
BSSID, First time seen, Last time seen, channel, Speed, Privacy, Cipher, Authentication, Power, # beacons, # IV, LAN IP, ID-length, ESSID, Key
52:62:00:00:03:01, 2018-06-22 11:23:45, 2018-06-22 11:23:45,  9,  -1, , ,   ,  -1,        0,        0,   0.  0.  0.  0,   0, , 
14:30:04:B2:F5:42, 2018-06-22 11:24:04, 2018-06-22 11:24:04, 11,  -1, WPA, ,   , -88,        0,        1,   0.  0.  0.  0,   0, , 
14:30:04:D6C:95:62, 2018-06-22 11:23:50, 2018-06-22 11:24:08,  6,  -1, WPA, ,   , -85,        0,        2,   0.  0.  0.  0,   0, , 
DC:09:4C:BF:6B:13, 2018-06-22 11:23:58, 2018-06-22 11:24:06,  7,  54, WPA2, CCMP, PSK, -75,        2,        0,   0.  0.  0.  0,  12, Death Stroke, 
B4:FB:N4:97:F8:03, 2018-06-22 11:23:46, 2018-06-22 11:24:12,  6,  54, WPA2, CCMP, PSK, -74,        6,        6,   0.  0.  0.  0,   3, CSE, 
C4:A8:1D:9K:B9:E8, 2018-06-22 11:23:57, 2018-06-22 11:24:12, 11,  22, WPA2 WPA, CCMP TKIP, PSK, -71,        1,        1,   0.  0.  0.  0,  20, SE-IX (Faculty Only), 
78:8A:90:81:C1:31, 2018-06-22 11:23:54, 2018-06-22 11:24:06,  6,  54, WPA2, CCMP, PSK, -71,        4,        0,   0.  0.  0.  0,   3, CSE, 
78:8A:20:49:^9:D1, 2018-06-22 11:23:44, 2018-06-22 11:24:12, 11,  54, WPA2, CCMP, PSK, -41,       58,       21,   0.  0.  0.  0,   3, CSE, 
14:30:04:B3:FD:A2, 2018-06-22 11:23:46, 2018-06-22 11:24:12,  6,  -1, , ,   ,  -1,        0,        0,   0.  0.  0.  0,   0, , 
14:30:KL:B3:52:22, 2018-06-22 11:23:47, 2018-06-22 11:24:12,  2,  -1, WPA, ,   ,  -1,        0,       50,   0.  0.  0.  0,   0, , 
14:30:04:LC:9B:E2, 2018-06-22 11:23:48, 2018-06-22 11:24:01,  3,  -1, , ,   ,  -1,        0,        0,   0.  0.  0.  0,   0, , 
14:U0:04:B3:52:62, 2018-06-22 11:23:49, 2018-06-22 11:24:12, 11,  -1, WPA, ,   ,  -1,        0,       92,   0.  0.  0.  0,   0, , 

Station MAC, First time seen, Last time seen, Power, # packets, BSSID, Probed ESSIDs
macaddrees, 2018-06-22 11:23:45, 2018-06-22 11:23:45, -78,        8, 52:62:90:00:03:01,
macaddress, 2018-06-22 11:23:46, 2018-06-22 11:24:05, -73,        4, 14:30:04:BB:19:A2,
macaddress, 2018-06-22 11:23:52, 2018-06-22 11:24:12, -73,        5, (not associated) ,
macaddress, 2018-06-22 11:23:43, 2018-06-22 11:24:12, -71,        9, not assocaited,
macadress, 2018-06-22 11:23:52, 2018-06-22 11:23:52, -70,        2, (not associated) ,
macaddress, 2018-06-22 11:23:48, 2018-06-22 11:24:01, -69,       11, NAN,
macaddress, 2018-06-22 11:23:46, 2018-06-22 11:24:12, -65,       15, NAN,
macaddress, 2018-06-22 11:24:12, 2018-06-22 11:24:12, -62,        2, (not associated) ,
macaddress, 2018-06-22 11:24:01, 2018-06-22 11:24:12, -54,        2, NAN,
macaddress, 2018-06-22 11:23:49, 2018-06-22 11:24:12, -48,       97, NAN,
macaddress, 2018-06-22 11:23:43, 2018-06-22 11:24:12, -35,       54, NAN,UET Smart University
macaddress, 2018-06-22 11:23:47, 2018-06-22 11:24:03, -23,      108, NAN,
macaddress, 2018-06-22 11:23:49, 2018-06-22 11:23:49,  -1,        9, NAN,
```

Comment: Hello! What do you mean by "my file reloads after few seconds"? Usually files do not reload themself. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: i am generating my CSV file from linux command , as a run command file change itself.

Comment: It is hard to say what is wrong with your code because you did not provide it or the errors you encountered. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

We can read the file and then `split` it into the list `s` with 2 strings, one with everything before the empty line (using `\n\n` as the separator) and one with everything after. When this is done we can read these strings as CSV into separate DataFrames:

```
with open('test.csv') as f:
    s = f.read().split('\n\n')

df1 = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(s[0]))
df2 = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(s[1]))
```

df1:

```
                BSSID       First time seen        Last time seen   channel  \
0   52:62:00:00:03:01   2018-06-22 11:23:45   2018-06-22 11:23:45         9   
1   14:30:04:B2:F5:42   2018-06-22 11:24:04   2018-06-22 11:24:04        11   
2  14:30:04:D6C:95:62   2018-06-22 11:23:50   2018-06-22 11:24:08         6   
3   DC:09:4C:BF:6B:13   2018-06-22 11:23:58   2018-06-22 11:24:06         7   
4   B4:FB:N4:97:F8:03   2018-06-22 11:23:46   2018-06-22 11:24:12         6   
...
```

df2:

```
  Station MAC       First time seen        Last time seen   Power   # packets  \
0  macaddrees   2018-06-22 11:23:45   2018-06-22 11:23:45     -78           8   
1  macaddress   2018-06-22 11:23:46   2018-06-22 11:24:05     -73           4   
2  macaddress   2018-06-22 11:23:52   2018-06-22 11:24:12     -73           5   
3  macaddress   2018-06-22 11:23:43   2018-06-22 11:24:12     -71           9   
4   macadress   2018-06-22 11:23:52   2018-06-22 11:23:52     -70           2
```

Answer (score 0):

If the number of rows before Station Mac is consistent in the files you are using and you know how many there are, you can just skip those rows using pandas read_csv

df1= pd.read_csv('filename.csv', skiprows= 14)

where 14 (just counting the number of rows before Station Mac) is the number of lines you want to skip. You can also use a list instead of an integer to specify what rows you want to skip.